# Highlight functionality same as medium application

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, rangy

I want to implement highlight functionality for my website and mobile app. I want this functionality work same as medium app. So that if user highlight some text from mobile application then it will automatically display on the website.

And if user highlight some text from the website then it will automatically display on the mobile app.

Previously I used rangy highlighter JavaScript library for both website and mobile app, But it gives different range from both side. So I am unable to sync the highlight data.

For example:

For mobile I get the following range

```
type:textContent|1362$1370$1$highlight$
```

For Website I get the following range

```
type:textContent|40576$40584$3$highlight$
```

Can anyone give me any idea, how can I sync my iOS app's highlighted data with website?

Comment: Please provide an example fiddle that shows your existing code.